# Cloud Functions and Firestore does not go up the root in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and 
setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.giveCard = functions.firestore
.document('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}/_given/{_givenID}')
.onWrite((event) => {

    // Get the field values of what I am working with
    const oldGiven = event.data.previous.data()['given'];
    const newGiven = event.data.data()['given'];

    // Get the cardID to make sure that is there
    const cardID = event.params.cardsId;

    // An array to go through
    const give_profiles = event.data.data()['given_profiles'];

    // error cardDatatwo is returned as undefined
    const cardDatatwo = newGiven.parent;

    // error cardDatathree is returned as undefined
    const cardDatathree = event.data.ref.root

    // // error cardDatafour cannot read propoerty of undefined
    // const cardDatafour = cardDatathree.child('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}')

    // error cardDatafive 'The value of cardfive is DocumentReference...
    const cardDatafive = event.data.ref.firestore.doc('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}');

    // Check that the values have changed
    if (newGiven == oldGiven) return;

    if (newGiven !== undefined) {

        console.log('The old value of given is', oldGiven);
        console.log('The new value of given is', newGiven);
        console.log('The value of the card is', cardID);
        console.log('The value of the cardtwo is', cardDatatwo);
        console.log('The value of the cardthree is', cardDatathree);
        // console.log('The value of the cardfour is', cardDatafour);
        console.log('The value of the cardfive is', cardDatafive);

        for (var profile of give_profiles) {
            console.log(profile);
        };
        return;
    }
    return console.log("No given value");
});
```

I am having great difficulty in getting the root for Firestore working with Cloud Functions. It works differently of course.

I am try to get a value up the path towards the root after an onUpdate has been fired further down.

.parent does not work
functions.database.ref of course does not work as that's the realtime database
and cannot use
firebase.firestore() is also not working in node
and event.data.ref.firestore.doc comes back as undefined.

I am sure have gone through every option.

Hope you can help.

Wo

Comment: Can you share some of your code to show how far you've got and where you need to implement `parent`? Would this be inside a listener callback with a `DocumentSnapshot`?

Comment: Please show your code, and also remember that you should update your firebase-admin module to the latest version to be able to use its Firestore APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#firestore), you can access collections via `firestore`, like this:

```
exports.giveCard = functions.firestore
.document('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}/_given/{_givenID}')
.onWrite((event) => {

    // other code

    const ref = event.data.ref.firestore.doc('your/path/here');
    return ref.set({foo: 'bar'}).then(res => {
      console.log('Document written');
    });

});
```

You can use `firestore` to build a path to whatever part of the database you're seeking to access. You can also use `event.data.ref.parent`, like so:

```
exports.giveCard = functions.firestore
.document('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}/_given/{_givenID}')
.onWrite((event) => {

    // other code

    const parentref = event.data.ref.parent;
    const grandparentref = parentref.parent; // gets to cardsId
    return grandparentref.set({foo: 'bar'}).then(res => {
      console.log('Document written');
    });

});
```

Comment: TY for the reply. Sorry, I should of put that one in also. I tried it before. Still undefined. I am sure now I have tried all the possible permutations. I have changed the code to add that one also with the error message.

Comment: It does work because I tried it myself. However, your reference `const cardDatafive = event.data.ref.firestore.doc('Profiles/{profileId}/cards/{cardsId}');` isn't going to work because of the curly braces. You can't have wildcards in a specific path where you're trying to write or read data.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to show an example using `event.data.ref.parent`, which works to access higher up the path where the write occurred.

Comment: Of course. My bad. You are using set and I should of been using .get to get the data. Got it working now.

I got confused as I was accessing particular fields in a document and should been thinking about the whole data in the doc. 

Documents, Fields, Maps. All very new to me. Thank you for your patience. By the way. Love the Youtube vids and thank you for answering my dumb question.