# Firestore access using Cloud Functions event

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with a few syntax issues

```
exports.deleteProject = functions.firestore.document('{userID}/projects/easy/{projectID}').onDelete(event => {
```

inside the functions I have

```
console.log(event)
```

which outputs

```
 { data: 
   DocumentSnapshot {
     _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: [Object], _referencePath: [Object] },
     _fieldsProto: undefined,
     _readTime: undefined,
     _createTime: undefined,
     _updateTime: undefined },
  eventId: 'd4079c38-2dc1-44e2-924d-fa27c3a95f8b-0',
  eventType: 'providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.delete',
  notSupported: {},
  params: 
   { userID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     projectID: 'dddddddddddd' },
  resource: 'projects/nnnnnnnnn/databases/(default)/documents/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/projects/easy/dddddddddddd',
  timestamp: '2017-11-11T04:41:16.712975Z' }
```

The problem I have is I can't seem to figure out the syntax to reference the database (and subsequently another collection/document path) itself or the different elements that appear when I print out event.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Example code in this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47091940/4815718.  And this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897702/4815718

Answer (score 3):

When you receive a Firestore event in Cloud Functions, it's an object of type `Event<DeltaDocumentSnapshot>`, which means `event.data` is of type [DeltaDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot).  With this, you can access the entire database using the received event via `event.data.ref.firestore`.  This gives you a [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.9.x/Firestore) object that you can use to access collections and documents within that instance of Firestore.  For example:

```
const firestore = event.data.ref.firestore
const docref = firestore.doc('collection/doc')
```

Also, you can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) (with its [Firestore API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore)) to access Firestore directly from any Cloud Function without a Firestore event.